# Как глобально инициализировать переменную из struсt?

Tags: c++

Есть код, который работает

```
struct shape {
    static shape *list; //Начало списка
    shape *next;
    shape() {next = list; list =this; }
};
shape *shape::list = nullptr;
void shape_refresh() //Функция не член класса
{
    //
    for(shape* p = shape::list; p; p = p->next) p->draw();
    //
}
```

Следующий код не работает:

```
struct shape { 
    static list <shape*> s_list;
    shape();
    virtual ~shape() { s_list.remove(this); }
};
shape *shape::s_list;  //Как в данном месте правильно инициализировать s_list глобально
                       //s_list не видна в цикле for

void shape_refresh(){   //Функция не член класса
    for (list <shape*> p = s_list; !p.empty(); p.pop_front()) p.front()->draw();
}
```

Comment: Во втором примере объявление `static list <shape*> s_list;`, а определение `shape *shape::s_list;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы хотите что-то вроде этого?

```
struct shape { 
    static list <shape*> s_list;
    shape() {};
    virtual ~shape() { s_list.remove(this); }
};

list<shape*> shape::s_list;  

void shape_refresh(){   //Функция не член класса
    for (list <shape*> p = shape::s_list; !p.empty(); p.pop_front()) p.front()->draw();
}
```